# list index out of range error when loading Feature-Barcode Matrices into Python

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to unzip and load a sparse matrix of genomic data into a csv file with the following code, which was obtained from [10X's website](https://support.10xgenomics.com/spatial-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/matrices?src=email&lss=internal&cnm=es-2019-09-marketing-video-ra_g-kol-visium&cid=&src=email&lss=internal&cnm=es-2019-09-marketing-video-ra_g-kol-visium&cid=#convert-mat).

```
import csv
import gzip
import os
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd
import json

matrix_dir = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix"
mat = scipy.io.mmread(os.path.join(matrix_dir, "GSM4775593_Q5matrix.mtx.gz"))

features_path = os.path.join(matrix_dir, "GSM4775593_Q5genes.tsv.gz")
feature_ids = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(features_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]
gene_names = [row[1] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(features_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]
feature_types = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(features_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]

barcodes_path = os.path.join(matrix_dir, "GSM4775593_Q5barcodes.tsv.gz")
barcodes = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(barcodes_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]
```

However, am receiving the following index out of range error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 18>()
 15 feature_types = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(features_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]
 17 barcodes_path = os.path.join(matrix_dir, "GSM4775593_Q5barcodes.tsv.gz")
---> 18 barcodes = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(barcodes_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]

Input In [20], in <listcomp>(.0)
 15 feature_types = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(features_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]
 17 barcodes_path = os.path.join(matrix_dir, "GSM4775593_Q5barcodes.tsv.gz")
---> 18 barcodes = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(gzip.open(barcodes_path, mode="rt"), delimiter="\t")]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Did you double-check that `row[2]` exists at all times?

Comment: The CSV-file seems to have an empty or incomplete line, probably at the end.